# How to mockout servicecall in jasmine test?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine, spy

I created an angular custom directive with a service called scriptingService in it. The goal is to mock the service call out with a spyOn. This is part of the test:

```
 beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile,_scriptingService_) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      scope.row = 1;

      scriptingService = _scriptingService_;
      Restangular = _Restangular_;

      spyOn(Restangular, 'all').and.callThrough();

      spyOn(scriptingService, 'getScript').and.callThrough();

      element = angular.element('<ul id="rows" ui-list="row">');
      $compile(element)(scope);
      scope.$digest();
    }));
```

This is the directive code:

```
.directive('uiList', [
    function(scriptingService) {
        return {
            scope: {
                lengthModel: '=uiList'
            },
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
                scope.$watch('lengthModel', function(newVal) {
                    scope.test=2;
                    console.log('kut');

                    scriptingService.getScript(request).then(function(scripts){
                        scope.scripts = scripts;
                    });

                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

However I am getting an error:

```
RestangularProvider <- Restangular <- scriptingService
```

How can I mock the scriptingService and make sure the method was called?
Plunker ref:http://plnkr.co/edit/CDc7EV?p=preview

Comment: Your plunkr has a few issues: old jasmin version combined with new syntax, and.callThrough() doesn't work in 1.3.1 (update jasmin or use andCallThrough()) and your scriptingService doesn't exist in the plunkr. 

The error "Unknown Provider" on the plunkr is expected as there is no such service registered with the module.

Comment: I updated the plunkr and added the scriptService. I mocked out the Restangular but still getting an error:Error: Unknown provider: RestangularProvider <- Restangular <- scriptingService

Comment: I can't see it on http://plnkr.co/edit/uhyzg6?p=preview

Comment: sorry just updated the link:http://plnkr.co/edit/CDc7EV?p=preview

Comment: In my opinion, the provided script isn't a good unit-test, are you testing a directive compilation? You need to mock everything else, included restangular. You don't need for a `callThrough`... you need to respond fake with the expected data... this in order to avoid test-failing if there are errors in your service.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. Like the comment said above, you need to use a newer version of jasmine for `callThrough` functionality, but also `Restangular` requires underscore, so that needs to be referenced as well in your html file.
2. Also, the dependency injection needed to be fixed for your directive, because it was not able to inject `scriptingService` properly, which never allowed it to call `scriptingService.getScript` since `scriptingService` was `undefined`. The issue is that

   ```
   [ function(scriptingService) {}]
   ```

   will not work to inject `scriptingService` into `uiList`. It just ends up being `undefined`.

   It needs to either be

   ```
   ['scriptingService', function(scriptingService) {}]
   ```

   OR

   ```
   function(scriptingService) {}
   ```

   For reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation
3. `request` is never defined when it's gets used in this code, I'm not sure what it's supposed to be.

   ```
   scriptingService.getScript(request).then(function(scripts) {
    scope.scripts = scripts;
   });
   ```
4. After fixing these issues, the test was still failing, saying Error: Unexpected request: GET /scripting.

   I was able to fix this by injecting `$httpBackend` (which is a service for mocking http calls in angular) into the tests and expecting a request. So I changed

   ```
   inject(function ($rootScope, $compile,_scriptingService_,_Restangular_)
   ```

   TO

   ```
   inject(function ($rootScope, $compile,_scriptingService_,_Restangular_, $httpBackend)
   ```

   and added this

   ```
   $httpBackend.expectGET("/scripting").respond([]);
   ```

   after the `spyOn`'s, then the test passed. I'm not sure exactly what this http call is supposed to return, but this is just an example of how you could test it.

   For reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend